# DIV dropdown (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm looking to create a basic DIV based dropdown menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">item 1</a>
        <div class="submenu">something here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">item 2</a>
        <div class="submenu">something else here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">item 3</a>
        <div class="submenu">something more</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$j('.submenu').hide()
$j("#menu li a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').next('.submenu').addClass('active').slideDown('fast');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').next('.submenu').addClass('active').slideUp('fast');
  }
);
```

... isn't working.

Comment: You probably want a semi-colon after this:
$j('.submenu').hide();  and the $j, is jquery referenced as such, or as the $ as on the $(this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul` is not beneath `#menu`, it **is** `#menu`, try this:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
  $j('.submenu').hide();
  $j("#menu li a").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).addClass('active').next('.submenu').addClass('active').slideDown('fast');
    }, 
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('.submenu').removeClass('active').slideUp('fast');
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"#menu ul li a"
```

references nothing.  menu is a ul

Comment: Oh sorry about that, nesting is not the problem in my case, I've verified it.

Comment: I just ran a simple test after removing ul and it worked.  I also changed $j to just $, but I'm not sure if you are using some kind of alias there.  I also added a semicolon after hide() and changed the quotes to double quotes in ".submenu"